# Google Maps API V2 blank map after installation on real device

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, apk, android-keystore

When I emulate the app from eclipse using the device everything's OK, but after I generate the apk file and have it installed, my map is blank.

I followed these steps:

1. Generate a new keytool

   ```
   keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-keystore-name.keystore
           -alias myKey1 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 20000
   ```
2. From Eclipse I "Export signed application package" using the keystore file (and key) I got from step 1.
3. Copy the apk to the device and select "package installer"

Manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="apt.login"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <permission

    android:name="apt.login.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"

    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission
    android:name="apt.login.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <application
        android:permission="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:testOnly="false"
        android:debuggable="true">    



         <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
         <meta-data

            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"

            android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>

         <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <activity
            android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.Loading">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.Mapa">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.Splitbar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Are you using debug Key for the Maps API? You need to generate a release KEY.

Comment: So... am I getting a debug key from step #1?? No release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try moving the `<meta-data/>` containing your API KEY to just before the  closing tag.

You also don't have the following in there and you should:

`<uses-feature
     android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
     android:required="true"/>`

Comment: You don't need to include openGl version in manifest anymore. But you still need the feature itself though

Comment: @FCo The map is working fine now! thank you very much for the heads up. I follow your indications about the manifest (I don't know why I just ignered them the first time: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start). I have generated a new key by "Export signed application package" in Eclipse as well (just in case).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a new key from eclipse, Android Tools -> Export signed package, create new keystore.

Generate the SHA-1 key, use it to get the API key and place it in the meta data present in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Use the keystore that you use for create .apk file of your project.

Open terminal and write below command keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name after your press enter it will ask you for password give your keystore password. press enter. it will genrate MD5 key & SHA1 key.(key like this)

SHA1: BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:67:71:9B:62:90:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75

use this SHA1 key in googleconsole when you creating browser key for map.

This is work for me.