# Google Maps v2 show blank screen when export project (apk)

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

When I install my proyect using usb, the map works fine but when I want export my proyect (.apk) and install the app, the map doesn't work just show blank display. Any advice.

**UPDATE:** I have my proyect and google play services library in my dropbox and the debug.keystore in the root c:\Users\my_user.android\debug.keystore

I have tried to do this but without success: [Google Maps API V2 blank map after installation on real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254559/google-maps-api-v2-blank-map-after-installation-on-real-device)

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your SHA key in **google console project**.
You just replace exported SHA with old SHA key.

Exported SHA get like.
1) Export your project with create key store at that time you get exported SHA .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That was the solution, I needed the release key. Here is how to do that. [Displaying the release certificate fingerprint](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Answer (score 0):

After implementing maps layout activity and manifest and other required files , the app should be build with the keystore provided in android sdk itself instead of our own keystore. keystore path - C/user/{username}/.android/debug.keystore with alias as "androiddebugkey" and password as "android"